# OPTIONS Http request is failing with 404 exception while Post request is working fine

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, http-options-method

I've a rest endpoint with an optional PathVariable in spring framework.

```
@PostMapping("/API_PATH/{param1}/{param2}")
public Result getResult(@PathVariable Integer param1,
    @PathVariable(required = false) Integer param2, @RequestBody Data data) {
    // SOME LOGIC HERE
}
```

I've marked `param2` Path variable as not required. So it is an optional value. This POST API works fine when I don't send any value to `param2`. But when the browser tries to access this API, it sends an `OPTIONS` type of request before sending the actuals `POST` request. Now if the `OPTIONS` reqeust doesn't contain the second path variable  (`param2`) in the URL, it is failing with 404 exception. Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: have you configured your server to handle CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)? Without CORS Configuration, POST will not work from a browser. However, same POST request will work from Postman/Android even without CORS configuration.

Comment: I've configured CORS. And other POST requests are working from browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OPTIONS requests are what we call pre-flight requests in Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) which checks the safety measures. For the same, you may need to add CORS Configurations

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

---

Some Other Ways of CORS Configuration
Using `CorsRegistry`:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/api/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://domain1.com","http://domain2.com");
}
```

---

Using `@CrossOrigin`:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://domain1.com","http://domain2.com"})
```

---

Using `application.properties`

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://domain1.com,http://domain2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is specifically for a `POST`, so there is no handler for an `OPTIONS`. Spring provides a `CrossOrigin` annotation that implements the pre-flight CORS handler, have a read [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

Try this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping("/API_PATH/{param1}/{param2}")
public Result getResult(@PathVariable Integer param1,
@PathVariable(required = false) Integer param2, @RequestBody Data data) {
    // SOME LOGIC HERE
}
```